# Prove elements of $D_8$ and $\left \langle (1\; 2\; 3) \right \rangle$ do not commute in $S_4$

Tags: group-theory

The complete question is:

Fix any labelling of the vertices of a square and use this to identify $D_8$ as a subgroup of $S_4$, then prove that elements of $D_8$ and $\left \langle (1 \;2 \;3) \right \rangle$ do not commute in $S_4$.

The first part is easy. But for the second part, denote $H$ as the set of elements of $D_8$ and $K=\left \langle (1 \;2 \;3) \right \rangle$. How to prove $HK=KH$? Notice $HK=KH$ does not imply that elements of $H$ commute with those of $K$.

Comment: One way of handling the second part is to choose two generators of $H$, call them $h_1$ and $h_2$. Then you would need to show that $K^{-1}h_iK$ is an element of $H$, for both values of $i$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course the identities will commute with other elements.

Otherwise, let $x$ be a nontrivial element of $D_8$ and $y$ be a nontrivial element of $<(1 2 3)>$. Then $x$ has as its order either $2$ or $4$, and $y$ has order $3$. If $x$ and $y$ commuted, then since the orders are coprime, $xy$ would have order either $6$ or $12$.

This can't be true, since $S_4$ has no elements of order $6$ or $12$.

Comment: But the question does not require $xy$ in $S_4$, and by the way, how could $xy$ not in $S_4$? $xy$ is just some permutation of {1,2,3,4}

Comment: @Ian Of course $xy$ lies with $x$ and $y$ in $S_4$. If we assume $x$ and $y$ commute, though, we come to a contradiction, so the conclusion must be that $x$ and $y$ do not commute